# Changing Host Instance in BizTalk Deployment Framework

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, btdf

I am using BizTalk Deployment Framework to deploy my application. It is working in local machine. I want to deploy in Test Environment and it should be using Visual studio not by MSI. I am not sure where to change the HostInstance name.

Answer (score 3):

First, it's just better if the Host names are the same in DEV and all other environments.  It makes things easier.

However, if you really need them to be different, you just have to configure the Host names as Settings, using the Settings file, so BTDF can dynamically set them at Deploy time.

For clarity, you should be using a .msi to deploy to TEST, not Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a little further, here's an example of where you'd set the host name in PortBindingsMaster - note that it's a per artifact configuration (i.e. each orchestration, send port, and receive location has its own host specified).  I completely agree with Johns-305, host names should definitely be the same across all environments - it makes life much easier and much less confusing (and you're less likely to introduce some deployment issue because you forgot to configure the right host name for TEST vs DEV).  Just configure your dev environment to mirror TESt/PROD.  And you should do this initially by exporting your bindings to be sure you get the correct `Capabilities` and `ConfigurationClsid` values.

For an Orchestration:

```xml
<Service Name="OrchestrationName" State="Started" TrackingOption="ServiceStartEnd MessageSendReceive OrchestrationEvents" Description="">
  <Ports>
      ...
  </Ports>
  <Roles />
  <Host Name="OrchHost" NTGroupName="${SsoAppUserGroup}" Type="1" Trusted="false" />
</Service>
```

You could replace the `Name` attribute value of the `Host` with your host variable name, e.g. `${OrchHostName}` (assuming you have a line in your SettingsFileGenerator.xml with the first column name being `OrchHostName`).

For a ReceiveLocation:

```xml
<ReceiveLocation Name="rlocBlahBlah_FILE">
  ...
  <ReceiveHandler Name="ReceiveHost" HostTrusted="false">
    <TransportType Name="FILE" Capabilities="11" ConfigurationClsid="5e49e3a6-b4fc-4077-b44c-22f34a242fdb" />
  </ReceiveHandler>
</ReceiveLocation>
```

You could replace the `Name` attribute value of the `ReceiveHandler` with your host variable name, e.g. `${ReceiveHostName}`.

For a SendPort:

```xml
<SendPort ...>
...
  <PrimaryTransport>
    ...
    <SendHandler Name="SendHost" HostTrusted="false">
      <TransportType Name="FILE" Capabilities="11" ConfigurationClsid="5e49e3a6-b4fc-4077-b44c-22f34a242fdb" />
    </SendHandler>
  </PrimaryTransport>
  <SecondaryTransport> <!-- if configured -->
    <SendHandler Name="SendHost" HostTrusted="false">
      <TransportType Name="FILE" Capabilities="11" ConfigurationClsid="5e49e3a6-b4fc-4077-b44c-22f34a242fdb" />
    </SendHandler>
  </SecondaryTransport>
   ...
</SendPort>
```

Secondary transport is not required and not configured by default, but should be taken into account if you're using it.  You could replace the `Name` attribute of the `SendHandler`s with something like `${SendHandlerName}`.